# Why does my replace regex does not give the right outcome?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have this cmd output, which I use as an string input in my VB.NET application:

```
output1: unshared
owner: unknown
public: EU
scope: this
value type: string
enum values: "----- / ASIL C", "SIL 0 / QM", "SIL 1 / ASIL A", "SIL 2 / ASIL B", "SIL 3 / ASIL D"
```

What I'm trying to achieve is getting the data from the enum values, getting rid of the special symbols and spaces (not including the , symbol) and making an string array out of it. So the output string should look like

`"ASILC","SIL0QM","SIL1ASILA","SIL2ASILB","SIL3ASILD"`

but the regex, that replaces the symbols is really bothering me.

My code:

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim values As String = "CMD OUTPUT"

        Dim pattern As String = "enum values:\s*(.*)" 'finding the right data line
        Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(values, pattern)
        Dim retVal As String() = New String() {}
        Dim locVal As String = " "

        If match.Success Then
            Dim capturedContent As String = match.Groups(1).Value
            locVal = Regex.Replace(capturedContent, """(.+?)""\s*(,|$)\s*", "$1$2") 'getting rid of special symbols/spaces
            Dim names As String() = locVal.Split(New Char() {","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            retVal = names
        End If
    End Sub
```

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe something like https://ideone.com/zs34qR?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works well, but the output value is not string array :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion how you could solve it:

1. Get the whole line as you do
2. Split the line on comma to get separate values
3. In a loop, strip special chars from each value and add to `retVal`

Code maybe bit wrong, but it gives the idea and has some more explanations:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim values As String = "CMD OUTPUT"

    Dim pattern As String = "enum values:\s*(.+)" 'finding the right data line
    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(values, pattern)
    Dim retVal As String() = New String() {}
    Dim locVal As String = " "

    If match.Success Then
        Dim capturedContent As String = match.Groups(1).Value
        locVal = capturedContent.Split(',') 'split by comma
        
        For Each enumVal In locVal
            ' \W is non-word character, which will match all special chars at once
            ' It's enough to replace it with empty string.
            Dim finalValue = Regex.Replace(enumVal, "\\W", "")
            ' add finalValue to retVal
            
        Next enumVal
        
        retVal = names
    End If
End Sub
```